# Count the Number of A's repeated consecutively repeated and how many times repeated?

Tags: c#

Lets say an array having 'p' and 'a'

```
string[] value = new string[] {"p","p",**"a","a","a","a"**,"p","p",**"a","a"**,"p"};
```

Count of Consecutive a's

```
repeat count --> Count of consecutive
1             -> 4
2             -> 2
```

I need this kind of output. it doesn't not matter which method or format you use.

Note: The length of array is not constant.

Comment: Did you try anything? What difficulties are you having implementing this?

Comment: I am a novice and I know how to count the total of repeated values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a quick and simple example of one way you can iterate through a list and find duplicates, by keeping track of the last character and comparing it to the current one, and maintaining a count of duplicates.

I'm using an array of `char[]` since this seemed more appropriate than using a `string` to store a single character.

If you want to extend the logic to do only 'p' and 'a' I'm sure you can use the below code as a good base sample and build from there.

```
char[] values = new char[] { 'p', 'p', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'a', 'a', 'p' };

char lastChar = values.FirstOrDefault();
List<int> consecutiveCount = new List<int>();
int i = 0;
foreach (char value in values)
{
    if (value == lastChar)
    {
        i++;
        continue;
    }

    consecutiveCount.Add(i);
    lastChar = value;
    i = 1;
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", consecutiveCount));
```